# elasticsearch exact matching string include dot

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have the following indexed document:

```
curl -XGET "http://127.0.0.1:8200/logstash-test/1/_search"

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "logstash-test",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "AVthzksHqNe69jLmmCEp",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "bar2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "logstash-test",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "AVthzlbfqNe69jLmmCSr",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "bar3"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "logstash-test",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "AVthwg4_qNe69jLmlStd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "bar"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "logstash-test",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "AVth0IS1qNe69jLmmMpZ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "bar4.foo_bar.foo"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to search `foo=bar2 or foo=ba3 or foo=bar4.foo_bar.foo`

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:8200/logstash-test/1/_search" -d 
    '{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"foo":["bar3","bar2","bar4.foo_bar.foo"]}}]}}}'
```

But `bar4.foo_bar.foo` do not match.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you are searching on exact terms use `keyword` field available on `foo` field as shown below:

```
  curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:8200/logstash-test/1/_search" -d 
  '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "foo.keyword": [
              "bar3",
              "bar2",
              "bar4.foo_bar.foo"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

You can read more about `multi-fields` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields)

**Method #2**

You can solve it by using different `analyzer`( e.g `whitespace` analyzer) for `foo` field while defining mapping for it.

```
PUT logstash-test
{
 "mappings": {
    "1": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "whitespace" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But as your are searching on `exact terms` *method #1* is preferred over *method #2*